# Regarding force download of a pdf file on clicking submit button after data is stored in database

Tags: php, wordpress

I have used the following code to store the data in wordpress database when submit button is clicked , And right now the code works by submitting the data to the wordpress database .

```
   if ($_POST['subscribe_btn']) 
    {
    require("connect.php");
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    if($user) 
    { 
    if(preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", $email)){
    $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_newslettter WHERE email='$email'") or exit(mysql_error());
    $numrows= mysql_num_rows($query);
   if($numrows == 0 )

    {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO wp_newslettter (`name`,`email`) VALUES ('$user','$email')")or exit(mysql_error());
    }
    else 
    $errmsg = "email address already exists";
    }
    else
    $errmsg = "Please enter a valid email address";
   } 

    else 
   $errmsg = "Please enter your username";
}
```

what i am now trying to do is once the data has been saved to the database i would like to force download a pdf which is stored in my theme , i am really new to wordpress and am not able to access the file path , i have done the following code but no file downloads , pls any help regarding this will be grateful and my form action is as follows `action='$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]'`

/****Code For downloading pdf after data submission ***/

```
$a =  bloginfo('template_url');
$file= $a . "/pdf/default.pdf";

$path_parts = pathinfo($file);
$ext = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]); 
switch ($ext) {
  case "pdf": $ctype="application/pdf"; break;
  case "exe": $ctype="application/octet-stream"; break;
  case "zip": $ctype="application/zip"; break;
  case "doc": 
  case "docx":  $ctype="application/msword"; break;
  case "xls": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-excel"; break;
  case "ppt": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"; break;
  case "gif": $ctype="image/gif"; break;
  case "png": $ctype="image/png"; break;
  case "jpeg":
  case "jpg": $ctype="image/jpg"; break;
  default: $ctype="application/force-download";
} 
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
header("Content-type:  $ctype"); 
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate , post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
exit;
```

I am unable to read the file by doing the following code

Comment: You overwrite two of your headers - cache-control and content-type.

Comment: I am not able to get the download file ... i think the problem is the path .. but am not sure ... same thing am able to do with normal php files but not when i do using wordpresss

Answer (score 0):

If the file is in your Media library, try viewing it and looking at the URL your browser goes to. This is the URL you need to take the user to with `header('Location: http://www.yoursite.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/22/file.pdf');` after the data submission.

Comment: i am storing the pdf inside my themes i.e  $a =  bloginfo('template_url');
$file= $a . "/pdf/default.pdf"; $file conatins the location

Answer (score 0):

function DisplayFiles() {

```
$results = GetFiles(); // Function that gets files available for download 
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $results ); // Get first row 

echo "    <select name='files'>\n"; 
while ( $row ) { 
    echo        "<option value = '" . $row['EightDigitValue'] . "'>" .$row['FileName']. "</option>\n"; 
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $results ); 
} 
echo "    </select>\n";
```

}